# Django Gunicorn Nginx *254 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Unknown error)

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am attempting to deploy a Django application on a Ubuntu 22.04 EC2 instance to the web following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@codewithmuh/host-django-application-using-gunicorn-nginx-in-production-on-aws-ubuntu-server-4b1551e13c66

I cannot access the contents of my application/project when I go through these steps, search my Public IPv4 address (even when I have it included in my list of allowed hosts).

My folder path is /home/ubuntu/portfolio/portfolio and I'm using miniconda as my venv

My configs are:

**Settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['18.189.143.92']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "home.apps.HomeConfig",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django_extensions",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]
```

**sites-enabled/sites-available**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/ubuntu/portfolio/portfolio;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}
```

**gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/portfolio/portfolio
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/portfolio/portfolio/env/bin/gunicorn \
        --access-logfile - \
        --workers 3 \
        --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
        --timeout 60 \
        portfolio.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**gunicorn.socket**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

The error I'm getting:

```
2023/11/22 19:31:08 [error] 17524#17524: *10 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: 130.211.54.158, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "18.189.143.92"
```